# Using Envers, how can I query historical data and not have missing child entity data in the queried revision of the parent table?

Tags: hibernate, annotations, hibernate-envers

I have several tables in my hibernate DB. When I query my DB for entity TABLE_A I get access to the collections within TABLE_C and TABLE_D because of how my tables are structured. Now as far as envers, my problem is that when I query for a revision of TABLE_A I don't see data for the collections of TABLE_C and TABLE_D...those entities are null. I think I understand why but I don't know how to configure envers to track data across all the tables so I don't get null entities when I query for revisions. For example, my application executes a transaction that updates data in TABLE_D but NOT TABLE_A, TABLE_B or TABLE_C for this specific transaction resulting in a revision being added only to TABLE_D_AUD, but not TABLE_A_AUD, TABLE_B_AUD, or TABLE_C_AUD.

So My question is, if no data is changed in TABLE_A_AUD, TABLE_B_AUD, or TABLE_C_AUD, and only TABLE_D causing the rev number to increment for TABLE_D revisions then how do I configure things so that when I get revisions for TABLE_A, I see the latest changes of the child table, TABLE_D? The problem is the rev numbers get off because TABLE_D gets changed and the others don't but they are all connected.

Also another side thought, If a revision is created for each table that is touched during a hibernate transaction then how do I get a revision without any missing data from child tables if those child tables were not touched within the transaction?

```
**TABLE A:**

@Entity()
@Audited
@Table(name = "TABLE_A")

@Column(name = "ID")
private Long id;
@Column(name = "NAME", length = 50)
private String name;

@OneToMany(
            mappedBy = "table_a",
            cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST}
    )
    @org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade(
            {org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE, org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN}
    )
    private Collection<TABLE_B> table_b = new ArrayList<TABLE_B>();




**TABLE B:**


@Entity()
@Audited
@Table(name = "TABLE_B")

@Column(name = "ID")
private Long id;
@Column(name = "NAME", length = 50)
private String name;

@XmlTransient
@ManyToOne()
@JoinColumn(name = "ID_TABLE_B", nullable = false)
private TABLE_A table_a;

@ManyToOne(
        cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST})
@org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade(
        {org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE}
)
@JoinColumn(name = "ID_TABLE_C")
private TABLE_C table_c;

@ManyToOne(
        cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST})
@org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade(
        {org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE}
)
@JoinColumn(name = "ID_TABLE_D", nullable = true)
private TABLE_D table_d;



**TABLE C:**

@Entity()
@Audited
@Table(name = "TABLE_C")

@Column(name = "ID")
private Long id;
@Column(name = "NAME", length = 50)
private String name;


@OneToMany(
        mappedBy = "table_c",
        cascade = {
                CascadeType.REMOVE})
@org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade(
        {org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE,
                org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.MERGE,
                org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN}
)
@XmlTransient
private Collection<TABLE_B> table_b = new HashSet<TABLE_B>();



**TABLE D:**

@Entity()
@Audited
@Table(name = "TABLE_D")

@Column(name = "ID")
private Long id;
@Column(name = "NAME", length = 50)
private String name;

@XmlTransient
@OneToMany(
        mappedBy = "table_d",
        cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST}
)
private Collection<TABLE_B> table_b = new ArrayList<TABLE_B>();
```